# If a bullet is shot up in the air off a cliff, will the final velocity be greater?

Tags: kinematics, velocity, free-fall

Since acceleration due to gravity is 9.80m/s^2 wouldn't the final velocity keep increasing by 9.80m/s each second that the bullet is in the air since velocity has a time dependence?

[image]

If that is the case for this scenario, what if we made the cliff sufficiently larger to produce a change in velocity?

If the velocity is the same whether you shoot a bullet straight up or straight down from the cliff then no matter at what point you release an object from any height, it will always have the same velocity?

Comment: You may want to rephrase you question title to remove wording "up in the air" since it doesn't look like you're asking for an analysis including air resistance.

Answer (score 0):

> "If the velocity is the same whether you shoot a bullet straight up or straight down from the cliff then no matter at what point you release an object from **any height**, it will always have the same velocity?"

(Emphasis mine)

The same height is one of the most important factors in this relationship.

You should be able to test this yourself.  You are able to use the one dimensional kinematic equations to determine the final velocity given various starting heights (you can also confirm the results of the book).

I'll leave the math for you to explore.

Answer (score 0):

Yes if the bullet continues falling past the launch point its speed will increase above 30m/s, by 9.8m/s every second.

If an object is launched at one height with a fixed speed and lands at another height, it will always have the same speed when it lands, regardless of which direction it was fired. The increase/decrease in speed between launch and landing points only depends on the vertical distance between them, not the horizontal distance, nor the angle at which it was fired.